# Volley's NetworkImageView getting cleared on ListView scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, android-volley, getview, networkimageview

I am using `NetworkImageView` provided by **Volley** for loading images in custom list view. At first launch it works fine, but once i scroll the list view then all the records got the first item image. I have already used View holder tagging stuff. Please suggest how this can be avoided.

Comment: Code of your CustomList Adapter please!

Comment: Mithun.. i am new here and its not allowing me to add the code , giving lot of errors.

Comment: how about putting it in https://pastelink.net/ and share the link?

Comment: @Mithun https://pastelink.net/display?q=gk

Comment: Please delete your answer below :)

Comment: `ImageLoaderProvider.loadImageInImageView( viewHolder.assetBidCardImageView, asset.getThumbnailUrl() , R.drawable.commercial_default_image );
 else
 viewHolder.assetBidCardImageView.setImageBitmap(null);`

I am not sure whats going on inside `ImageLoaderProvider.loadImageInImageView`. Also, could you let me know while scrolling are you able to see the default image you have set or its the image of the first `NetworkImageView` in your list? some screenshot also would be good (you can use http://imagebin.ca/)

Comment: I am getting the first record image in all the records. Its going in else but still setting the first record image. Loader works fine on individual elements like without list view, just placing the networkimageview on ui directly.

Comment: Could you please share `ImageLoaderProvider.loadImageInImageView` method. I am interested what API of `NetworkImageView` you are using in it.

Comment: Great! Please share your solution :)

Comment: //  Setting Url
            if (!StringHelper.isStringNullOrEmpty(imageURL))
            {
                imageView.setImageUrl(imageURL, mImageLoader);
            }
            else
                imageView.setImageUrl(null,mImageLoader); We have to set the imageurl to null , otherwise it will just show random things from the cache.

Comment: Sorry for such a poor typo stuff.. i didn't understand the formatting here. :)

Comment: Yes that's what I thought :) because were using `setImageBitmap()` Good that you figured out..

Comment: Mithun...did u have worked with edittext in listview ? I have edittext in all the records, and when i am entering value in any edittext then after scroll the same values also came up in other records . Any idea for this?